# split a mathematical expression on operators and include the operators in the output array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to split the mathematical strings on maths operators. for example

`expression = "7*6+3/2-5*6+(7-2)*5"`

I need to tokenize it to produce:

`expressionArray = ["7","*","6","+","3","/","2","-","5","*","6"]`

I tried finding the solution here and this is what i get

```js
expressoinArray=expression.split("(?<=[-+*/])|(?=[-+*/]")
```

but looks like this is not fetching the desired result for `expression`.

Comment: Aren't you missing a `+` between `"6","3"`

Comment: What is with expressions like 1--2?

Comment: Is `String1` a type of input, or the desired output?

Comment: This question makes little sense. The `String` isn't a string, and `String1` is an Array of some, but not all, of the tokens used to assigned to `String`. The value passed to `.split()` is a string sequence of characters seemingly unrelated to anything, though it looks like it could be intended to operate as a regex. And the desired input and output are unclear.

Comment: You say it isn't the desired result, but you also don't say what the desired result is.

Comment: I think this question is valid and needs to be reopened. One use case for this when converting postfix mathematical notation to prefix using shant yard algorithm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KJ6Tv/1/)

```
var expression = "7.2*6+3/2-5*6+(7-2)*5";
var copy = expression;

expression = expression.replace(/[0-9]+/g, "#").replace(/[\(|\|\.)]/g, "");
var numbers = copy.split(/[^0-9\.]+/);
var operators = expression.split("#").filter(function(n){return n});
var result = [];

for(i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
     result.push(numbers[i]);
     if (i < operators.length) result.push(operators[i]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The filter method doesn't work in IE 8 or below, just FYI.

Comment: I want to split at operators only, this won't give right result i I have decimal number or more than one digit number. for ex: 7.5*32+2-6.97

Comment: @min2bro - first off you didn't mention that, second this is all the way there minus changing the regex to get floats.

Comment: @Gabe Thanks much...I'll try some other way to get this done...

Comment: @min2bro - updated to support floats.

Comment: @min2bro - Legends always like upvotes.

Comment: @ I'm yet a novice to upvote legends..Need 9 more reputations to have this privilege to vote..

Comment: Quality down-vote there, give me a reason.

Comment: Note that this answer (and the one below it) don't work with expressions like `5 + -5`. Still a pretty good answer imo, just need that tiny fix.

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT:**

This works like the accepted answer and as a bonus won't fail due to `filter()` in IE8 and below:

```
var expression = "7.2*6+3/2-5*6+(7-2)*5";
var splitUp = expression.match(/[^\d()]+|[\d.]+/g);
document.body.innerHTML = splitUp;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/smAPk/

Comment: Your solution is elegant, but both you and the accepted answer have a bug. the following expression `5 + -1` returns `['5', '+ -', '1']`, which doesn't make much sense.. You still got my upvote though ;)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to use a regular expression with `split()` you have to create it first:

```
var expr = new RegExp("(?<=[-+*/])|(?=[-+*/])")  
// note: you missed a ) at the end
```

Sadly, the RegExp engine in most browsers doesn't support lookbehinds, so it won't work anyway. You have to do this in a loop.